# Structuring Django Project

Tags: python, django

I know that you're supposed to have a templates folder within each app folder, how I have two questions clarify further. 1, Should I have 2 base.html files (one in each app) that are identical? This seems like it's creating more files than need be... and 2. What about the static and media folders? Should I also have two of each or should they be at the project and app folders level?

If there is supposed to be a static folder in each app folder then do I have two css files? I feel like that makes no sense since the css can cover things that overlap from app to app.

I'm also wondering if have it setup the way I currently have it will effect anything, or if "best practice" is more so just for if you're working on a project with multiple people (which I'm not, in which case should I care?)

Here is my current structure:

```
/evverest/
    /evverest/
    /feed/
    /users/
    /blog/
    /templates/
        /base/
        /feed/
        /users/
    /static/
        /css/
    /media/
        /post_pics/
        /profile_pics/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a little bit confusing. I like to do this:

1. Global templates should live in the main `templates/` folder. This should include `base.html` and any other templates from other plugins that you're overriding.
2. App-specific templates should live in their own `templates/` folder inside the app, e.g. `blog/templates/blog/blog_index.html`. These templates should `{% extend 'base.html' %}` so that all apps in the project are using the same base template, which is in the global templates folder.
3. Assets should live in your global `STATIC_ROOT` folder from your Django settings, which I've called `assets` below. I'd stick to using the one folder for simplicity.

Here's an example of how this would look:

```
./evverest
├── evverest/
├── feed/
│   ├── templates/feed/feed_index.html
│   └── models.py
├── users/
│   ├── templates/users/users_index.html
│   └── models.py
├── templates/
│   └── base.html
├── static/
│   └── css/main.css
└── manage.py
```

For more on best practices, check out [`cookiecutter-django`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django). There's quite a lot to learn, but they're interested in following best practices, so it's a great resource.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, I reorganized it and it still works so thats good, I just wasn't sure what the best way to do this was. Thank you.

Comment: @Garrett Happy to help! I hope you enjoy using Django as much as I do. It's really pleasant to work with once you've gotten the hang of it.

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely getting there and it's great so far.